# Charger is not charging laptop (Charging icon is not displayed)

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, charging

First, Sorry for bad English.

I am having a problem with my laptop. My charger is plugged in and I have bought it just a couple of weeks ago. It was working just fine but since yesterday, it does not charge my laptop. No matter what I do, charging icon doesn't show up.[image: Here's A screenshot]

**NOTE** I am running Windows 10.

**UPDATE** It starts working once I restart my computer. But as I put it to Sleep again and open it, it again starts the same problem.
Please help.

Comment: Do you have the power management software installed with the computer manufacturer? Change the Power setting in Control Panel to check.
reinstall the video card driver and batteries (Microsoft AC Adapter driver) in device management to check.

Comment: So the physical charger itself works, but after sleep there's just no icon? What happens if you leave it plugged in after sleep, will it run forever or drain the battery & die?

Comment: Maybe you want to do a proper reboot, not the hybrid thing Windows 10 does. Also check firmware and manufacturer drivers.